# Declare variable and if statement in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am developing an application with python Django 
what I need to do is to assign a class to a div based on the counter variable value in templates

```
  {% with 1 as counters %}  
     {% for importance in all_importance %}

            {% if counters == 1 %}
                <div class="item active" >
            {% else %}
                <div class="item" >         
            {% endif %} 
            {% for image in importance.subtypemodelimage_set.all %}
                <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" />
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
        {% counters += 1 %} 
     {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}
```

But I face this issue

```
  Invalid block tag: 'counters', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'
```

where am I making mistake, thanks in advance for your helps

Comment: Instead of starting a counter yourself, Django does this for you.

Comment: @digaph could you please tell me how to do it, I do appreciate if you can provide a code snippet for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The for loop sets a number of variables available within the loop (full list in django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)):

```
...
forloop.first   True if this is the first time through the loop
forloop.last    True if this is the last time through the loop
...
```

you can use `forloop.first` to check for first loop iteration:

```
{% for importance in all_importance %}

    {% if forloop.first %}
        <div class="item active" >
    {% else %}
        <div class="item" >         
    {% endif %} 

    {% for image in importance.subtypemodelimage_set.all %}
        <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" />
    {% endfor %}

        </div>

 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it definitely solve my issue in this scenario but because I'm a new user and I can't vote up and I just have to pick the correct answer could you please let me know what was wrong with my code I mean how to increment variables in Django template

Comment: @AminBastani you cant without custom template tags as i know, check this for example: http://www.soyoucode.com/2011/set-variable-django-template

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with

```
{% counters += 1 %}
```

There is not tag `counters`. You are interpreting variable as tag.
More over you can't implement that kind of for loop in django template.

Comment: As you can read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with the "old" style is still supported

Comment: @AlexanderMeesters, that has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: OEPS, sorry, indeed it doesn't, don't know what i was thinking, now ive re-read it, you are indeed correct. Maybe i need more coffee :-) anyways, my apologies!

Comment: @Rohan ok thanks for the answer but you just said that it is wrong, please correct me and tell me how to do it the right way

Comment: @AminBastani, django template does not have support to increment statements, so you can't do that.